# Exception "Stack_overflow" in ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I wanted to ask if the exception :"exception Stack_overflow" could be caused an infinite loop , particularly, the exception occurs in the following code :

```
    ( *the loop "while" should stop when both stacks are empty*)
    while (not (Stack.is_empty stackFalse) )|| ( not (Stack.is_empty stackTrue)) do     
    (
        if (not ( Stack.is_empty stackTrue )) then
        (
            let q1 = Stack.pop stackTrue in
            let (_,_,ptrs) = fst (Hashtbl.find graph ( fst q1) ) in
            List.iter ( fun elem -> 

                            let app = Hashtbl.find graph elem in
                            let (typeNode,last,ptrs')  = fst app in 

                            if typeNode = "Or-node" then
                            (
                                Stack.push (elem,true) stackTrue;
                                Hashtbl.add labeled elem true
                            )
                            else if last = false then                                                        
                                Hashtbl.replace graph elem ((typeNode,true,ptrs'),snd app)
                            else 
                            (
                                Stack.push (elem,true) stackTrue;
                                Hashtbl.add labeled elem true
                            )       ) ptrs ; 
         );

        if (not ( Stack.is_empty stackFalse )) then            
        (
            let q2 = Stack.pop stackFalse in
            let (_,_,ptrs1) = fst (Hashtbl.find graph (fst q2) )in

            List.iter ( fun elem -> 

                            let app = Hashtbl.find graph elem in
                            let (typeNode,last,ptrs')  = fst app in 

                            if typeNode = "And-node" then
                            (
                                Stack.push (elem,false) stackFalse;
                                Hashtbl.add labeled elem false
                            )                            
                            else if last = false then                                                        
                                Hashtbl.replace graph elem ((typeNode,true,ptrs'),snd app)
                            else 
                            (
                                Stack.push (elem,false) stackFalse;
                                Hashtbl.add labeled elem false
                            )   ) ptrs1 ;
        );

    )
    done;
```

Comment: To be more idiomatic to functional programming, you should replace your `Stack` with a list, and replace the `while` loop with a recursive call. Is there a reason why this section is programmed in an imperative style?

Comment: Generally no, while loops won't cause a stack overflow - there is no stack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Standard first-aid : recompile with -g and run with OCAMLRUNPARAM=b (cf manual) to see backtrace.

PS I would suspect structural comparison (e.g. used by Hashtbl.find), are there any circular references in hashtbl elements?

Answer (score 6):

The stack grows when you enter into a caller function. `while` loops and tail-calls do not grow the stack, so a Stack_overflow error cannot result from such as loop.

As ygrek suggested, a cyclic data structure may provoke a stack overflow if you use the structural comparison operator `=` on it. You use `=` in your code, and the `Hashtbl` module uses `Pervasives.compare` internally; if the hashtbl keys are cyclic, all key-using operations may run into infinite loop. In that case, a good fix would be to use the modularized form of `Hasthbl` (`Hashtbl.Make`) which allows you to provide a custom, cyclicity-aware equality function.

A more common cause for stack overflow is the fact that some of the functions of the `List` module of the standard library are not tail-recursive. If applied to big enough list with a small enough stack limit, they may cause stack overflows. In this case, using the `List` module of Extlib or Batteries -- which provides tailrec implementations -- is a good fix. This is not your problem here however, as `List.iter` *is* tail-recursive already.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers address the programming style, which is good: if you have a huge stack and can fix it programatically, that is best.

However, if there is nothing you can do then note that `ulimit -s` controls the max stack size.  For deep stacks in [Coccinelle](https://coccinelle.gitlabpages.inria.fr/website/) I was able to finish the transform with the following:

```sh
ulimit -s $((1024*1024))
```

Note that this specifies a 1GB stack and used about 2.4GB of RAM, but it worked!