# Exception Stack_overflow for big integer in recursive functions

Tags: ocaml, stack-overflow, fatal-error

My Quicksort code works for some values of N (size of list), but for big values (for example, N = 82031) the error returned by OCaml is:

> Fatal error: exception Stack_overflow.

What am I doing wrong?
Should I create an iterative version due to the fact that OCaml does not support recursive functions for big values?

```
let rec append l1 l2 =
  match l1 with
    | [] -> l2
    | x::xs -> x::(append xs l2)


let rec partition p l =
  match l with
    | [] -> ([],[])
    | x::xs ->
      let (cs,bs) = partition p xs in
      if p < x then
        (cs,x::bs)
      else
        (x::cs,bs)


let rec quicksort l = 
  match l with
  | [] -> []
  | x::xs ->
      let (ys, zs) = partition x xs in
      append (quicksort ys) (x :: (quicksort zs));;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that none of your recursive functions are tail-recursive.

Tail-recursivity means that no further actions should be done by the caller (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)). In that case, there is no need to keep the environment of the caller function and the stack is not filled with environments of recursive calls. A language like OCaml can compile that in an optimal way but for this you need to provide tail-recursive functions.

For example, your first function, `append` :

```
let rec append l1 l2 =
  match l1 with
    | [] -> l2
    | x::xs -> x::(append xs l2)
```

As you can see, after `append xs l2` has been called, the caller needs to execute `x :: ...` and this function end up by not being tail-recursive.

Another way of doing it in a tail-recursive way is this :

```
let append l1 l2 =
  let rec aux l1 l2 =
    match l1 with
      | [] -> l2
      | x::xs -> append xs (x :: l2)
  in aux (List.rev l1) l2
```

But, actually, you can try to use [`List.rev_append`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALrev_append) knowing that this function will append `l1` and `l2` but `l1` will be reversed (`List.rev_append [1;2;3] [4;5;6]` gives `[3;2;1;4;5;6]`)

Try to transform your other functions in tail-recursive ones and see what it gives you.

Comment: On the top of your i would add that she can also use List.partition instead of redefining her own. The partition of the stdlib is tail-recursive while her's is not

Answer (score 0):

Best to fix the underlying problem as noted above, but if you *really* need a big stack, set  `ulimit -s`.  See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71375559/14055985